# Earphones problem/ sleep mode/ MacBook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, music, headphones

I been trying to listen to the music in my MacBook Air early-2015 however when I close it the music stops. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

download NoSleep for mac, makes it so that your display doesn't sleep when you close the lid.